# Crontab not running and I am not sure how to pipe out the errors

Tags: python, cron

I have this in my crontab -e

`* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/backups/database/_scripts/example.py > /home/backups/database/_scripts/output.txt`

example.py writes to a file

```
import os
import time
import datetime

datetime = time.strftime('%m%d%Y-%H%M%S')

with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(datetime + "\n")
```

I have ran this on command line and it works `/usr/bin/python /home/backups/database/_scripts/example.py`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your `test.txt` file is located in `/home/backups/database/_scripts/`

change

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(datetime + "\n")
```

to

```
with open("/home/backups/database/_scripts/test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(datetime + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the beginning of your script, set execution privileges, and change your contrab entry to:

```
* * * * * /home/backups/database/_scripts/example.py > /home/backups/database/_scripts/output.txt
```

### Explanation:

According to contrab's man page example:

```
 # use /bin/sh to run commands, overriding the default set by cron
 SHELL=/bin/sh
 # mail any output to `paul', no matter whose crontab this is
 MAILTO=paul
 #
 # run five minutes after midnight, every day
 5 0 * * *       $HOME/bin/daily.job >> $HOME/tmp/out 2>&1*
```

as you can see cron uses a given SHELL by default, in the example this is changed to **SHELL=/bin/sh**. Obviously the shell by default in your system don't recognize `/usr/bin/python` as a script.

So, you can

1. Run directly the script adding the `#!/usr/bin/env python` line and execution privileges.
2. Set SHELL=/usr/bin/python (not sure if this have some disadvantage)

**NOTE:** I'm not aware if cron can detect you're trying to run a python script and call the python interpreter by it self.